# How to find programmatically (SSJS) what item of the underlying doc the UI input control on Xpage is bound to?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

The task is that I need to update the field of the underlying doc only given the id of the edit box or the combo box on the Xpage. All that has to happen before the page is actually saved. Cannot find any methods in UIComponent and subclasses that allow to find out the name of the actual doc item the current XSP input control is bound to.  Plz help.

Comment: Can you tell more about your use case? I actually have no idea what you want to do with this information :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, I'll give it a try. Here's the use case: I have several sections on my xpage with similar groups of fields ({f1_A, f2_A, f3_A}, {f1_B, f2_B, f3_B} etc) that may be added or eliminated by the user from the page by clicking "+" or "x" button in any order. Display is controlled by the rendering property of each section. When user clicks x, the section fields has to be cleaned. If I save the doc with section not rendered, the fields in the back end are not updated. So I need to do that in the x button code. To have a single function I need to know what my ui control is bound to.

Answer (score 2):

The following will get the Expression Language binding for a component with the id `inputText1`:

```
var inputText1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText = getComponent("inputText1");
var valBinding:com.sun.faces.el.ValueBindingImpl = inputText1.getValueBinding("value");
return valBinding.getExpressionString();
```

This will return e.g. "#{document1.myField}". Using basic string parsing, you should be able to get what you want.

Like Oliver, I'd be interested to hear the use case. It's not something I've had the need to use.

As a bonus, try looking in the Local folder in Package Explorer at an XPage / Custom Control. You'll see all the getters / setters for components on your XPage, which will give you hints for what properties and methods are available. F3 and F4 are very useful for seeing all methods/properties and class hierarchy.